# Program causes memory corruption while reallocating memory

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, realloc

I have a program with a 2D array. First I allocate array like this:

```
char **crossword;
crossword = (char **) malloc(n* sizeof(*crossword));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    crossword[i] = (char *)malloc(n);
```

Where n = 50.

I then have function, that reads strings from stdin. Problem is, I don't know how many or how long those strings are going to be.

```
void read(char **p,int *n)
{
char tmp = 0,prevtmp = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0,x;

while (1)
{
    prevtmp = tmp;
    tmp = getchar();
    if ((tmp == '\n' && prevtmp == '\n') || feof (stdin))
    {
        *n = i;
        break;
    }
    if (tmp == '\n')
    {
        p[i][j] = '\0';
        i++;
        if (i == *n)
        {
            p = (char **) realloc(p, 2*i); // if there is more strings than space for them, allocate more memory.
            for (x = i; x < 2*i; x++)
                p[x] = (char *) malloc (*n);

            *n *= 2;
        }
        j = 0;
        continue;
    }
    p[i][j] = tmp;
    j++;
    if (j == *n)
        p[i] = (char *)realloc(p[i], 2*j); //same as above
}
}
```

Function is called like this:

```
read(crossword,&n);
```

This function works fine, when there is no need for realloc (there is less than 50 strings, each smaller than 50 characters). But for large inputs, this fails with

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000014282f0 *** error.
```

I think my problem is at the part where I realloc more memory, here is output from valgrind:

```
==8885== Invalid write of size 1
==8885==    at 0x40084C: read (in /home/xerw/Dropbox/CVUT/PROGTEST/du6/a.out)
==8885==    by 0x40177F: main (in /home/xerw/Dropbox/CVUT/PROGTEST/du6/a.out)
==8885==  Address 0x51f2b88 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8885== 
==8885== Invalid write of size 8
==8885==    at 0x4008A6: read (in /home/xerw/Dropbox/CVUT/PROGTEST/du6/a.out)
==8885==    by 0x40177F: main (in /home/xerw/Dropbox/CVUT/PROGTEST/du6/a.out)
==8885==  Address 0x51f4f00 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:266 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.

==8885==    at 0x3804C6CF: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x3804C812: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x38000883: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x380574EA: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x38057E03: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x380212DC: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x3802146A: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x3808F656: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==8885==    by 0x3809E68C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==8885==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8885==    by 0x4008A5: read (in /home/xerw/Dropbox/CVUT/PROGTEST/du6/a.out)
==8885==    by 0x40177F: main (in /home/xerw/Dropbox/CVUT/PROGTEST/du6/a.out)
```

I've been experimenting with pointers for a short time, so I have no idea what is wrong. I've been trying to solve this for few hours, but I didn't come up with anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the type of crossword?

Comment: char **crossword, edited my post.

Comment: You do this `p = (char **) realloc(p, 2*i);` in your code. Is `p` pointing to crossword? If so, you had allocated crossword as with a size of `n * sizeof(*crossword)`. So is `2*i` correct? By the way, it's bad to call realloc and assign its result tot he pointer you're reallocating directly - if realloc() fails it leaks memory, cause your original pointer is now lost.

Comment: 2D arrays and double pointers are not the same thing. Using the [][] on a double pointer is always bad.  Please read this: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html.

Comment: @linuxuser27 Why is `stringArray[i][j]` bad to get the character at index `j` in the 0-terminated string pointed to by `stringArray[i]`? I find that much clearer than `*(*(stringArray + i) + j)` or `*(stringArray[i] + j)` or `(*(stringArray + i))[j]`.

Comment: `"This function works fine, when there is no need for realloc (there is less than 50 strings, each smaller than 50 characters). But for large inputs, this fails"` let me guess. You're using `crossword` after `read` returned? The `realloc` doesn't change the address stored in the `crossword` variable in the caller, so when `realloc` changes the location inside `read`, the caller is left with a dangling pointer. Writing through that can easily corrupt vital memory, using it in any way invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFisher so if I understand you correctly, realloc is only valid for the function it was called in?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the following line:

```
p = (char **) realloc(p, 2*i);
```

I guess it should be:

```
p = (char **) realloc(p, (2*i)*sizeof(char*));
```

i.e. you want to increase the array to hold `2*i` elements, so you need to allocate `2*i` times the size of `char*`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that,  but my program still crashes, this time with a different error. I'm posting from phone right now and I don't remember the exact error, will look into that tomorrow morning.